# Restore Database from dump.sql

Tags: postgresql, database-restore

I am getting this error while restoring data from the dump file.

```
nishant@nishant-Lenovo-G50-70:~/Documents$ psql sortation_gor1 < dump.sql
psql: FATAL:  role "nishant" does not exist
```

I have followed the [Postgress Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/postgresql.html)
But when I am trying to restore the database I am getting this error.
Any IDea. ?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL `pg_dump` doesn't save a roles. Roles in PostgreSQL are related to database cluster, not to single database. It does `pg_dumpall` with option `-r`. You should to create missing roles manually with SQL statement `CREATE ROLE name LOGIN` or you have to use export roles with `pg_dump -r`.

Comment: But I thought, Postgres by default may have postgres as a default role. I tried it switching to the postgres user but I still get the error: psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres".

Comment: And the owner of the database is postgres.

Comment: And when I did postgres=# CREATE ROLE postgres;It showns this ERROR:  role "postgres" already exists.

Comment: I opened the dump.sql file and saw this line ALTER TABLE public.auth_group OWNER TO sortation_gor; and finally created a new role sortation_gor.but still i am not able to restore my DB.

Comment: If i do it with the ubuntu postgres user then : psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres".And with the nishant user psql: FATAL:  role "nishant" does not exist. I think I need to add a ubuntu user sortation_gor to restore the file ..?

Comment: you should to edit `pg_hba.conf` - enable a access for postgres user

Answer (score 0):

The I did it with the `psql -U postgres -d d1atabase_name -f dump.sql`